# Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value x within timeout of 30000:

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, listener, spring-jms

I am using spring boot 1.5.8. I have configured 2 jms listeners. When I am trying to shut down gracefully using kill sigterm, I'm getting this exception.

```
13-06-2018 13:21:16 :: WARN  :: defaultValueForJmsMessageId::[Thread-2] :: Failed to shut down 1 bean with phase value 2147483647 within timeout of 30000: [org.springframework.jms.config.internalJmsListenerEndpointRegistry]
13-06-2018 13:21:19 :: ERROR :: defaultValueForJmsMessageId::[AMQP Connection 10.23.219.62:5672] :: An unexpected connection driver error occured
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/utility/Utility
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.broadcastShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:273)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.finishProcessShutdownSignal(ChannelN.java:291)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.access$000(ChannelN.java:50)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN$1.transformReply(ChannelN.java:588)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN$1.transformReply(ChannelN.java:585)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.handleCommand(AMQChannel.java:356)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:149)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.utility.Utility
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
13-06-2018 13:21:29 :: WARN  :: defaultValueForJmsMessageId::[Thread-2] :: Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'rabbitConnectionFactory': java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/impl/SocketFrameHandler$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has happened when the application was not given enough time to stop and when restart happened immediately after the deployment of updated spring boot jar in same location.
This has not happened after giving enough time. Will update if something comes up.